# Using rdstate() to ensure valid input

Tags: c++, validation, input

I am trying to write a method to gather input from the user. One that will print an error message if anything but the correct 2 values are input. My professor LOVES to break code, and he'll sit there and bang his head on the keyboard until something breaks through. Simply using `cin.good()` or `cin.fail()` isn't good enough, because there are certain keystrokes that will not be flagged, such as entering ctrl+z or certain other strings.

I've been told that using `rdstate()` is the only way to ensure a user error is flagged, no matter what keystroke combination is entered.

**This method is to gather input from the user, make sure it is an integer (either 1 or 2), and then do logic based on the user input.** Would it be better to gather input with `getline()` and then convert to an integer with `atoi()`? Or use the `>>` operator to put the input straight into a variable as an integer? I have heard the `>>` gets really messy when handling errors. I'm new to C++ and unsure of best practice.

```
do {
    cout << "Press enter to advance: ";
    getline(cin, answer);
    int state = cin.rdstate();
    if(state!=0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, please press enter.... " << state << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        cin.clear();
        if(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()>0)
        {
            getline(cin, answer);
            continue;
        }
    }
} while (answer == "\n");
```

This was my first attempt at writing a test function to see if I had the right idea. It doesn't work. Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Any input I enter will allow the loop to break, and advance the code. It should be throwing an error for anything that isn't a "\n".

Comment: There's no reason to filter bad input, when you really only want to be checking for good input.

Comment: What are the "correct two values" you are looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure if I understand your question. You say that the user must input an integer and that the program should warn "invalid input" in case the user enters a string, for example?

Comment: Like it says in the description, my professor will basically not accept any code he can break. By that I mean, he will purposefully enter bad input into our programs to test if we can successfully handle the errors. If not, we get no points. So I need to write code that ONLY ACCEPTS the correct input, otherwise will alert the user of their error, and loop to try again.

Comment: ok, and the correct input is? an integer?

Comment: In the sample code I provided, I ask the user to press "enter".

Comment: @xavi Isn't there a rubric or a set of things he will do to break your program? Why would he give a vague problem statement?

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzy question. I attempted to ask the question in a way that would allow me to write this code for use with my problem now and in the future!

Comment: He will do everything in his power to break it. The problem I am solving is not this specific one. Writing code that correctly handles all errors is just an inherent part of the course.

Comment: Is the user expected to press "1<CR>", or just "1"?

Comment: Should `cin.clear()` be called before the first `getline(cin, answer)`?

Comment: My advice is start simple with what works for correct input, then work on handling edge cases.  I also think you're incorrect about having to check `rdstate()` directly, but if you do you should use the proper constants and not 0 to check against.